# /proc/meminfo shows MemFree greater than MemAvailable - Does it make sense?

Tags: memory, proc, free

From what I could understand from [this change](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=34e431b0ae398fc54ea69ff85ec700722c9da773) in Linux reported memory usage, `/proc/meminfo` reports `MemFree` as currently unused RAM, and `MemAvailable` as RAM currently available to new processes without swapping.

From this, shouldn't `MemFree` be contained in `MemAvailable`, thus being always less or equal than it? I guess unused RAM is also available to new processes without swapping. Or am I misunderstanding the "Free memory cannot be taken below the low watermark" (4th chunk from patch) part?

These values match, as expected, `free` and `top` outputs.

I saw this in an Exadata virtual machine with these specs:

```
cat /etc/oracle-release 
Oracle Linux Server release 7.8

uname -r
4.14.35-1902.306.2.1.el7uek.x86_64

rpm -q sysstat
sysstat-10.1.5-19.el7.x86_64
```

Full `/proc/meminfo` at an arbitrary moment, if it helps:

```
MemTotal:       19995464 kB
MemFree:         2963684 kB
MemAvailable:    1063344 kB
Buffers:          406124 kB
Cached:          2609256 kB
SwapCached:         9648 kB
Active:          4632640 kB
Inactive:        2348256 kB
Active(anon):    3882372 kB
Inactive(anon):   700524 kB
Active(file):     750268 kB
Inactive(file):  1647732 kB
Unevictable:      634040 kB
Mlocked:          634044 kB
SwapTotal:      16777212 kB
SwapFree:       16579068 kB
Dirty:              1684 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       4592704 kB
Mapped:           384108 kB
Shmem:            484212 kB
Slab:             511064 kB
SReclaimable:     249660 kB
SUnreclaim:       261404 kB
KernelStack:       23184 kB
PageTables:        96648 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    24602016 kB
Committed_AS:    5737344 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:    2122
HugePages_Free:      590
HugePages_Rsvd:        1
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      833536 kB
DirectMap2M:    15943680 kB
DirectMap1G:     5242880 kB
```

Thanks,
Emerson

Comment: The formula for MemAvailable is in the code you linked to.

Comment: @AlexD Yes. The problem is my understanding - from that formula, is it possible to have more available RAM than free RAM?

Comment: `available = i.freeram - wmark_low`. It means that the value initially assigned to `MemAvailable` is `(MemFree - low watermark)` which is less than `MemFree`.

Comment: @AlexD Makes sense. The low watermark can be greater than the other components of MemAvailable. I really thought it was impossible, but maybe it's a normal edge case.
I guess that's it. Would you repost that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code starts as `available = i.freeram - wmark_low`.

It means that the value initially assigned to `MemAvailable` is `(MemFree - low watermark)` which is less than `MemFree`.